# asyncio catch TimeoutError in Task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have an `asyncio.Task` that I need to cancel after some amount of time. Before cancelling, the task needs to do some cleanup. According to the docs, I should just be able to call task.cancel or `asyncio.wait_for(coroutine, delay)` and intercept an `asyncio.TimeoutError` in the coroutine, but the following example is not working. I've tried intercepting other errors, and calling `task.cancel` instead, but neither have worked. Am I misunderstanding how cancelling a task works?

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def toTimeout():
  try:
    i = 0
    while True:
      print("iteration ", i, "......"); i += 1
      yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    print("timed out")

def main():
  #... do some stuff
  yield from asyncio.wait_for(toTimeout(), 10)
  #... do some more stuff

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation for `asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) specifies that it will cancel the underlying task, and then raise `TimeoutError` from the `wait_for` call itself:

> Returns result of the Future or coroutine. When a timeout occurs, it
>   cancels the task and raises `asyncio.TimeoutError`.

And you are correct that task cancellation [can indeed be intercepted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel):

> [`Task.cancel`] arranges for a `CancelledError` to be thrown into the wrapped
>   coroutine on the next cycle through the event loop. The coroutine then
>   has a chance to clean up or even deny the request using
>   `try`/`except`/`finally`.

Note that the docs specify that `CancelledError` is thrown into the coroutine, not `TimeoutError`.

If you make that adjustment, things work the way you expect:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def toTimeout():
  try:
    i = 0
    while True:
      print("iteration ", i, "......"); i += 1
      yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
  except asyncio.CancelledError:
    print("timed out")

def main():
  #... do some stuff
  yield from asyncio.wait_for(toTimeout(), 3)
  #... do some more stuff

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
iteration  0 ......
iteration  1 ......
iteration  2 ......
timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aio.py", line 18, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 316, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 275, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 238, in _step
    result = next(coro)
  File "aio.py", line 15, in main
    yield from asyncio.wait_for(toTimeout(), 3)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 381, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

As you can see, now `'timed out'` gets printed before the `TimeoutError` is raised by `wait_for`.